# what does 話通してます mean here?

Tags: translation

オレラ マサル君**に話 通し**てますよ。it translates as: we've already talked with Masaru-kun.

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48051/9831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「(人に)[話]{はなし}を[通]{とお}す」 means "talk to someone and get consent (in advance)" "run it by someone" (事前に話して了承を得る).

> オレラ マサル君に話 通してますよ。

Here a few particles are omitted. してます is a contraction of しています.

> オレラ**は**、マサル君に話**を**通して**い**ますよ。

means "We have already talked to Masaru-kun and got his consent."

～ています here means "have already done" (not the present progressive "are doing ... now".) For more on this ～ている:

> [How is なっている different from なっていた?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3787/9831)